# Istanbul - Bosphorus at night

Tags: ferries, istanbul

Is it possible to do the Bosphorus strait ferry tour at night? I have a 22 hour layover in November this year in Istanbul and was wondering whether one of the things that I would be able to do, could be the tour of the Bosphorus strait at night.

Comment: As you're probably flying Turkish, you probably can claim a free city tour, or possibly even a hotel.

Comment: Yea, it is Turkish. Shall try to get tour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is.  But may depend on the time of year (during summer).  Most of them will offer you a meal along with a tour.

- [IDO Scenic Bosphorus Tour by Night (IDO Boğaziçi Özel Gezi)](http://www.istanbultrails.com/2009/06/dont-miss-out-on-a-bosphorus-cruise-tour-while-in-istanbul/).
- [Turnatour - Bosphorus Dinner Cruise](http://www.tripadvisor.co.nz/Attraction_Review-g293974-d2050099-Reviews-Turnatour_Bosphorus_Dinner_Cruise-Istanbul.html).
- [List of Tours](http://www.wittistanbul.com/magazine/what-bosphorus-cruise-tour-to-take-in-istanbul/)

From my own experience, I find it difficult to find info on these sorts of things online, but found it pretty straight forward by just going there and found plenty of ferry operators standing around selling you tickets.